# MediaPlayer OnCompletionListener never being triggered

Tags: android

I've implemented a MediaPlayer using the following code but it's never calling `onCompletion`.  I'm streaming mp3 from my LAN.  Any idea what's wrong?

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        // Nothing here gets executed
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
});

mMediaPlayer.reset();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement looping? If so then in onPrepared listener you could call mp.setLooping(true);

Comment: Are you calling MediaPlayer.release() anywhere? It will clear your OnCompletionListener.

Comment: @Josh527 I'm not doing looping, `start()` is just a placeholder.
@WindsurferOak I'm calling `release()` in the onPause of my Activity but that shouldn't affect this.

Comment: I think it could be since you are calling reset().                     In the media player source, reset clears the event handler. from the source...           // make sure none of the listeners get called anymore
1030        mEventHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

Comment: You're right, that was the problem.  Add answer and I'll mark it.  edit: Although it's interesting that the onPreparedListener doesn't get removed because the media still plays.